# Proper serialization of LocalTime through WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, nodatime

I'm having trouble serialising and de-serialising NodaTime's LocalTime through a WebAPI.

Class definition

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public LocalTime ExampleLocalTime { get; set; }
}
```

Try to serialize the output

```
// create example object
var exampleclass = new ExampleClass() 
{ 
    ExampleLocalTime = new LocalTime(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute) 
};
// serialise output
var jsonsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
};
jsonsettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
string exampleoutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exampleclass, Formatting.Indented, jsonsettings);
```

I want to time format formatted to a ISO like standard e.g. 12:34:53, but instead it de-serialisers to the following with local time represented as ticks;

{
  "ExampleLocalTime": {
    "ticks": 553800000000
  }
}

What do I need to add to avoid *Ticks* when de-serialising and serialising?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Noda Time has an additional NuGet package available for JSON.Net serialization.

```
PM>  Install-Package NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet
```

To use it, simply invoke its configuration extension method:

```
var jsonsettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
jsonsettings.ConfigureForNodaTime();
```

You can read more about it [in the Noda Time user guide](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/serialization.html) (about half-way down the page).